# Use a javascript variable with .attr() value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a javascript variable with .attr() value

My code :

```
var nombre_pv = 18;
var nombre_pv_max = 20; 
var pv_enlever = nombre_pv_max - nombre_pv ;
var pv = nombre_pv_max - pv_enlever;
var pv = pv/nombre_pv_max;
var pv = pv * 100;

$(".hp").attr("value", "/* insert pv here*/");
```

Comment: `$(".hp").val("");` ;)

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do ? Do you need to get the value attribute of an input form element with `hp` class and store in a js variable ?

Comment: I trying to update the value of an html element. With "var pv" on the "value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".hp").val(pv);
```

Or

```
$(".hp").prop("value", pv);
```

You might want to check out this answer to explain why the `value` attribute on an element is not the same as the property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/779323